# C# best way to implement TCP Client Server Application

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, client-server, tcpclient

I want to extend my experience with the .NET framework and want to build a client/server application. 
Actually, the client/server is a small Point Of Sale system but first, I want to focus on the communication between server and client. 
In the future, I want to make it a WPF application but for now, I simply started with a console application.

2 functionalities:

- client(s) receive(s) a dataset and every 15/30min an update with changed prices/new products
  (So the code will be in a Async method with a Thread.sleep for 15/30 mins).
- when closing the client application, sending a kind of a report (for example, an xml)

On the internet, I found lots of examples but i can't decide which one is the best/safest/performanced manner of working so i need some advice for which techniques i should implement.

**CLIENT/SERVER**

I want 1 server application that handles max 6 clients. I read that threads use a lot of mb and maybe a better way will be tasks with async/await functionallity.

*Example with ASYNC/AWAIT*

http://bsmadhu.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/simplify-asynchronous-programming-with-c-5-asyncawait/

*Example with THREADS*

mikeadev.net/2012/07/multi-threaded-tcp-server-in-csharp/

*Example with SOCKETS*

codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5306/tcp-socket-server

This seems to be a great example of sockets, however, the revisioned code isn't working completely because not all the classes are included
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx 
This example of MSDN has a lot more with Buffersize and a signal for the end of a message. I don't know if this just an "old way" to do this because in my previous examples, they just send a string from the client to the server and that's it.

*.NET FRAMEWORK REMOTING/ WCF*
I found also something about the remoting part of .NET and WCF but don' know if I need to implement this because i think the example with Async/Await isn't bad.

**SERIALIZED OBJECTS / DATASET / XML**

What is the best way to send data between it? Juse an XML serializer or just binary?

*Example with Dataset -> XML*

stackoverflow.com/questions/8384014/convert-dataset-to-xml

*Example with Remoting*

akadia.com/services/dotnet_dataset_remoting.html

If I should use the Async/Await method, is it right to something like this in the serverapplication:

```
        while(true)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if(input == "products")
                SendProductToClients(port);
            if(input == "rapport")
            {
                string Example = Console.ReadLine();
            }                                
        }
```

Comment: Is this a TCP exercise? if not, use a higher-level protocol such as web-services or HTTP. TCP programming is very hard.

Comment: I just want to send data from the server to the client in an efficient way.

Comment: First, this seems like two completely different questions: "which network API to use?" and "how to serialize data?" They are related, but not really the same questions. Second, in a modern C# program I would go with the first option: async/await using TcpClient/TcpListener. You may or may not want to follow that example precisely, but it seems like a good starting point. More to the point, async/await provides a very clean and easy way to deal with this exact scenario. Definitely do not use the threading example; that's the least efficient, least scalable approach.

Comment: I recommend [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr).

Comment: I think SignalR is more for realtime applications. Thx @PeterDuniho for your tips, I will work out this example!

Comment: *So the code will be in a Async method with a Thread.sleep for 15/30 mins*. That's an astonishingly bad idea. Use a Timer of some kind for the sender, and an event of some type for the receiver.

Comment: I am working on vehicle Tracking System. I did TCP listner server
 I implement code in Windows Service. when i start service port goes open its ok. while after client connect its work, but when client send data to server automatically service stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads are not terribly expensive, considering the amount of RAM available on modern systems, so I don't think it's helpful to optimize for a low thread count. Especially if we're talking about a difference between 1 thread and 2-5 threads. (With hundreds or thousands of threads, the cost of a thread starts to matter.)

But you do want to optimize for minimal blocking of whatever threads you do have. So for example instead of using Thread.Sleep to do work on 15 minute intervals, just set a timer, let the thread return, and trust the system to invoke your code 15 minutes later. And instead of blocking operations for reading or writing information over the network, use non-blocking operations.

The async/await pattern is the new hotness for asynchronous programming on .Net, and it is a big improvement over the Begin/End pattern that dates back to .Net 1.0. Code written with async/await is still using threads, it is just using features of C# and .Net to hide a lot of the complexity of threads from you - and for the most part, it hides the stuff that should be hidden, so that you can focus your attention on your application's features rather than the details of multi-threaded programming.

So my advice is to use the async/await approach for all of your IO (network and disk) and use timers for periodic chores like sending those updates you mentioned.

And about serialization...

One of the biggest advantages of XML over binary formats is that you can save your XML transmissions to disk and open them up using readily-available tools to confirm that the payload really contains the data that you thought would be in there. So I tend to avoid binary formats unless bandwidth is scarce - and even then, it's useful to develop most of the app using a text-friendly format like XML, and then switch to binary after the basic mechanism of sending and receiving data have been fleshed out.

So my vote is for XML.

And regarding your code example, well ther's no async/await in it...

But first, note that a typical simple TCP server will have a small loop that listens for incoming connections and starts a thread to hanadle each new connection. The code for the connection thread will then listen for incoming data, process it, and send an appropriate response. So the listen-for-new-connections code and the handle-a-single-connection code are completely separate.

So anyway, the connection thread code might look similar to what you wrote, but instead of just calling ReadLine you'd do something like "string line = await ReadLine();" The await keyword is approximately where your code lets one thread exit (after invoking ReadLine) and then resumes on another thread (when the result of ReadLine is available). Except that awaitable methods should have a name that ends with Async, for example ReadLineAsync. Reading a line of text from the network is not a bad idea, but you'll have to write ReadLineAsync yourself, building upon the existing network API.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here are several things anyone writing a client/server application should consider:

- Application layer packets may span multiple TCP packets.
- Multiple application layer packets may be contained within a single TCP packet.
- Encryption.
- Authentication.
- Lost and unresponsive clients.
- Data serialization format.
- Thread based or asynchronous socket readers.

Retrieving packets properly requires a wrapper protocol around your data.  The protocol can be very simple.  For example, it may be as simple as an integer that specifies the payload length.  The snippet I have provided below was taken directly from the open source client/server application framework project [DotNetOpenServer](https://github.com/UpperSetting/DotNetOpenServerSDK) available on GitHub.  Note this code is used by both the client and the server:

```
private byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
private int payloadLength;
private int payloadPosition;
private MemoryStream packet = new MemoryStream();
private PacketReadTypes readState;
private Stream stream;

private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        int available = stream.EndRead(ar);
        int position = 0;

        while (available > 0)
        {
            int lengthToRead;
            if (readState == PacketReadTypes.Header)
            {
                lengthToRead = (int)packet.Position + available >= SessionLayerProtocol.HEADER_LENGTH ?
                        SessionLayerProtocol.HEADER_LENGTH - (int)packet.Position :
                        available;

                packet.Write(buffer, position, lengthToRead);
                position += lengthToRead;
                available -= lengthToRead;

                if (packet.Position >= SessionLayerProtocol.HEADER_LENGTH)
                    readState = PacketReadTypes.HeaderComplete;
            }

            if (readState == PacketReadTypes.HeaderComplete)
            {
                packet.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(packet, Encoding.UTF8);

                ushort protocolId = br.ReadUInt16();
                if (protocolId != SessionLayerProtocol.PROTOCAL_IDENTIFIER)
                    throw new Exception(ErrorTypes.INVALID_PROTOCOL);

                payloadLength = br.ReadInt32();
                readState = PacketReadTypes.Payload;
            }

            if (readState == PacketReadTypes.Payload)
            {
                lengthToRead = available >= payloadLength - payloadPosition ?
                    payloadLength - payloadPosition :
                    available;

                packet.Write(buffer, position, lengthToRead);
                position += lengthToRead;
                available -= lengthToRead;
                payloadPosition += lengthToRead;

                if (packet.Position >= SessionLayerProtocol.HEADER_LENGTH + payloadLength)
                {
                    if (Logger.LogPackets)
                        Log(Level.Debug, "RECV: " + ToHexString(packet.ToArray(), 0, (int)packet.Length));

                    MemoryStream handlerMS = new MemoryStream(packet.ToArray());
                    handlerMS.Seek(SessionLayerProtocol.HEADER_LENGTH, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(handlerMS, Encoding.UTF8);

                    if (!ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(OnPacketReceivedThreadPoolCallback, br))
                        throw new Exception(ErrorTypes.NO_MORE_THREADS_AVAILABLE);

                    Reset();
                }
            }
        }

        stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), null);
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ConnectionLost(ex);
    }
}


private void Reset()
{
    readState = PacketReadTypes.Header;
    packet = new MemoryStream();
    payloadLength = 0;
    payloadPosition = 0;
}
```

If you're transmitting point of sale information, it should be encrypted.  I suggest TLS which is easily enabled on through .Net.  The code is very simple and there are quite a few samples out there so for brevity I'm not going to show it here.  If you are interested, you can find an example implementation in DotNetOpenServer.

All connections should be authenticated.  There are many ways to accomplish this.  I've use Windows Authentication (NTLM) as well as Basic.  Although NTLM is powerful as well as automatic it is limited to specific platforms.  Basic authentication simply passes a username and password after the socket has been encrypted.  Basic authentication can still, however; authenticate  the username/password combination against the local server or domain controller essentially impersonating NTLM.  The latter method enables developers to easily create non-Windows client applications that run on iOS, Mac, Unix/Linux flavors as well as Java platforms (although some Java implementations support NTLM).  Your server implementation should never allow application data to be transferred until after the session has been authenticated.

There are only a few things we can count on: taxes, networks failing and client applications hanging.  It's just the nature of things.  Your server should implement a method to clean up both lost and hung client sessions.  I've accomplished this in many client/server frameworks through a keep-alive (AKA heartbeat) protocol.  On the server side I implement a timer that is reset every time a client sends a packet, any packet.  If the server doesn't receive a packet within the timeout, the session is closed.   The keep-alive protocol is used to send packets when other application layer protocols are idle.  Since your application only sends XML once every 15 minutes sending a keep-alive packet once a minute would able the server side to issue an alert to the administrator when a connection is lost prior to the 15 minute interval possibly enabling the IT department to resolve a network issue in a more timely fashion.

Next, data format.  In your case XML is great.  XML enables you to change up the payload however you want whenever you want.  If you really need speed, then binary will always trump the bloated nature of string represented data.

Finally, as @NSFW already stated, threads or asynchronous doesn't really matter in your case.  I've written servers that scale to 10000 connections based on threads as well as asynchronous callbacks.  It's all really the same thing when it comes down to it.  As @NSFW said, most of us are using asynchronous callbacks now and the latest server implementation I've written follows that model as well.